Illegal Instruction Error when Building Vapor Project on Server
My vapor project runs fine on my local machine, but when I try to build it on the server (Ubuntu 22.04) I get an error. I installed Swift and Vapor on the server prior to building the project. The picture I'm attaching shows a backtrace; can anyone help me make sense of this or how to trace the problem?
EDIT: After vzsg's comment I increased the server memory to 4 GB. Signal 9 is no longer referenced in the error: this picture is the updated error.

Upon further inspection I found these other error messages saying there is no formatted function for a Date type. Perhaps the two errors are linked.


The key is "signal 9". Your server ran out of memory while trying to build the app.

I increased the memory size to 4 GB. The error no longer references signal 9 but it still crashes during build with "Illegal instruction."

Did you try to build your project in container with ready-made docker image?

No I did not, but I am highly intrigued, any advice for going about doing that?

Indeed, the two errors are "linked". The build failed because you are calling methods (Date.formatted) that are not available on Linux. I'm not aware of any drop-in replacements, you might have to implement all the formatting by hand.
